# Need help trimming CSV file with awk and sed without hacking it

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have searched stack and I am getting stuck with a particular CSV file:

I have a large CSV file formatted in two columns:

```
Name    Extension
Brian Aducci    6598
Jeff Alexander  6661
Sara Alfieri    6789
```

I want to leave the extension and trim the names into the usernames:

```
Name    Extension
BAducci 6598
JAlexander 6661
SAlfieri 6789
```

Comment: Any way of converting `Brian Aducci` to `BAducci`? Is it first name's first char & last name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this short line should give you what you want:

```
awk 'NR>1{$0=substr($1,0,1)$2" "$3}1' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo "Name    Extension
Brian Aducci    6598
Jeff Alexander  6661
Sara Alfieri    6789"|awk 'NR>1{$0=substr($1,0,1)$2" "$3}1'
Name    Extension
BAducci 6598
JAlexander 6661
SAlfieri 6789
```

Answer (score 0):

let's assume it's not 2, but "at least 3" columns... firsname lastname extension

And maybe there is more than 1 firstname (this happens a lot)

And let's assume:  the login is the 1st char of the 1st column, + the n-1th column (=the name)

you'd do:

```
gawk '(NR == 1) { print ; next ;} /./ { name=NF-1 ; print substr($1,1,1) $name " " $NF }' /the/file
```

This will work if you have

```
Name    Extension
firstname1                lastname1   extension1
firstname2a  firsntname2b lastname2   extension2
...
```

(ie whatever how many firstnames, 1 or more) (and however many space or tabs separate each fields)

the `(NR == 1) { print ; next ; }` part is to print the first (header) line "as is" and then "next" to the other lines.  You can take this out if you don't have the header.

On those other lines, NR>1, so only the 2nd pattern (`/./`, meaning "if the line is not empty") applies, and it prints what you need (change it if there are weird names like : john john name1 name2, but it should be rare)

You can also use gnu awk (or nawk) 'tolower' to force something to be lowercase:

```
gawk '(NR == 1) { print ; next ;} /./ { name=NF-1 ; print tolower(substr($1,1,1)) tolower($name) " " $NF }' /the/file
```

Comment: this works for 2 columns name, of course. But also works if a person have more than 1 firstname (assuming it's written as:  "firstname1 fierstname2 ... lastname extension")

Comment: @sudo_O I downvoted yours because it was not working, not for being compact... And i took back my downvote once it was working again, so it's no longer downvoted by me. So... why your downvote here, exactly?... is it some kind of a vendetta?

Comment: it does work. just change "/the/file" to point to the file containing the data. Or take "/the/file" out , and use the remaining line in a pipe.

Comment: ??? it does not. the questino doesn't show any commas, I copy/paste the 4 lines he shows, and my program displays exactly what he shows he expects to see. Stop saying misinformations. And I repeat : I took out my downvote as soon as yours was corrected to work. stop being childish and saying misinformations...

Comment: My answer was **always** working not matter how the records are separated, read the comments and you will see that user19340357 was **mistaken** it was actually his file that was wrong not my code. Also please note that **user19340357** isn't the OP, the OP is **user1991065** so the record separator has not be clarified (not that is matters). Your answer isn't well written, your code is hacked together and you make assumptions that aren't valid (number of fields and pointless mention of `tolower()`) -1.

Answer (score 0):

Any way of converting `Brian Aducci` to `BAducci`?

Is it first name's first char & last name? If yes, then below should work:

```
{read x; echo $x; while read x y; do echo ${x:0:1}$y; done; } <large_file >output_file
```

sed method:

```
sed -r '1!s/^(.)[^ ]* */\1/' large_file >output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`awk '{if( NR==1 ){print $1" "$2; next}}{a=substr($1,1,1); print a$2" "$3}' temp.txt`

Comment: names could have one or more firstnames... I tried to cover for that (but could be even more complicated, in some countries...). and header may vary too... I just print it bare

Comment: Olivier, can you give an example input?

Comment: @OlivierDulacc  i am a newbie , currently i can only provide solution for based on user input and his expected output. I can make many assumptions and that way i would never be able to answer single question . But OP has right to try every solution and choose which works for him. and i will also try learn more from you people

Comment: @user19340357 Of course, but I was just pointing out not to make assumptions there is only 2 columns for the name part. ex: John Lewis Smith. Your example is, however, **good** for the "firstname=$1 lastname=$2" case. And we all keep learning :) (I learn a lot reading top answers on those sites)

Comment: my answer does work. Both for names like the poster shows : "firstname lastname" but also for the (possibly present, doesn't hurt to accoutn for it) case of "firsname1 firsname2 ... lastname"

Answer (score 0):

awk would be my choice

```
awk 'NF>2{ for (i=1;i<NF -1;i++){ initials=initials substr($i,0,1) }; print initials $(NF-1), $NF}' x.txt
```

which checks the number of fields (NF) is greater than 2
then loops over fields 1 - NF-1
then takes the first letter of each and puts it into the initials variable.
Then we print out the initials the last name and the extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually easier with `sed`:

```
$ cat file
Name   Extension
Brian  Aducci     6598
Jeff   Alexander  6661
Sara   Alfieri    6789

$ sed -r '2,$s/(.)\w+\s+/\1/' file
Name        Extension
BAducci     6598
JAlexander  6661
SAlfieri    6789
```

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{sub(/\w+\s+/,substr($0,1,1),$0)}1' file
Name        Extension
BAducci     6598
JAlexander  6661
SAlfieri    6789
```

Comment: @i tried sed solution is not working. i have space separated file

Comment: @user19340357 The `sed` solution is tested on both and works `GNU sed` that is, are you on `OSX`?

Comment: ^sudo_O : I am now confused: why do you show a "solution" for a test file that is not the one the asker have? ... His doesn't have ',' but space(s) to separate fielsd

Comment: I am on Linux , its not printing the firstLtter of first word but only second word. like this `sed -nr '1p;2,${s/(.)\w+\s+/\1/p}' temp.txt
 Name    Extension
 Aducci    6598
 Alexander  6661
 Alfieri    6789`

Comment: @OlivierDulac because I read the question and the OP said he had a CSV file (Comma Separated Values), Only now is it clear which.. Both solution works for both anyway so why the -1?

Comment: Now your solution is working for the file , i think i had the extra space before the first column , thats why it was not working. what is the purpose for `${expression}` in sed

Comment: @sudo_O : csv is Character Separated Value. I will now retrieve my -1, now that it works for him. Of course I still prefer my way as it doesn't assume only 1 firstname ^^ But it's just "bonus", I agree

Comment: @user19340357 curly braces are used to [group](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35) commands in `sed` not actually necessary in this case. If you found this answer the most useful (elegant) please consider accepting it by click the tick next to it.

Comment: @sudo sorry dude, i not the one who asked the question, but your solution did not worked if we have extra whitespace in front of names, which can happen in data files

Comment: That is an easy fix, see updated answer. @OlivierDulac since when? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: @sudo_O : I cite the very link you just pointed out : "A CSV file consists of any number of records, separated by line breaks of some kind; each record consists of **fields, separated by some other character or string, most commonly a literal comma or tab**. Usually, all records have an identical sequence of fields." Hence the C is really Character (unless you name the tab-separated file 'tsv', etc...)

Comment: @WilliamPursell very true.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as Sudo_O's `sed` solution.  The trouble with using `sed` for this sort of thing is that there are many versions of `sed` which simply do not support the features used.  (For example, `-r` is a non-standard option used to make `+` be a magic character in the regex.  Many `sed` simply do not provide support for `+`)

```
perl -pe 's/^(.)/\S*\s/$1/ if $. > 1' input-file
```

Comment: `Many sed simply do not provide support for +` which implementations of `sed` don't support extended regular expression? While `-r` is the GNU option it also supports `-E` which is the BSD option for this *(the reverse not being true).

Comment: `-e`, `-f`, and `-n` are the only standard options.  Anything else cannot be used reliably.